# Valid8 jquery plugin: dependent field validation?

Tags: jquery

My client has required that I use a specific validation plugin (valid8), which seems to only do inline validation on focus. The documentation on the plugin is pretty weak, so I'm hoping someone else has experience with this particular plugin and they can help me out.

It's a contact form, where users must specify their preferred method of contact. If they specify email, then the email input field must be validated; if they specify phone, then the phone input field must be validated. I can selectively ADD the validation based on the radio selected, but I can't REMOVE validation if the user changes their contact preference before submitting the form.

Is there a way to remove valid8 validation from a field after it has been added using this plugin? I tried .unbind(valid8), but that doesn't work because unbind is for events, and valid8 is not an event. Do I have to manually unbind all events and remove the extra markup from the field?

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/sjc8611/5d3CT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this plugin but looking at the source it seems that information about validation for `#element` is stored in the arbitrary data `settings`, so you can try:

```
$('#element').data('settings', null);
```

And see what it does. It may generate errors though and if it does you can also remove the events associated it with, which are:

```
keyup
blur
click (for checkbox)
```

You can do it with just one command like this:

```
$('#element').unbind();
```

But this will remove ALL events for that element and again may cause problems, which is why I supplied the list above so you can remove them one by one if you need.

This is as much as I can say without ever using this, if it doesn't work you should post an example online (prefferably on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) so we can have a look at it. If all else fails you can email the plugin author.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjc8611/5d3CT/ go to town. I tried unbind and to set the settings to null. If I don't figure it out soon I'm just going to write my own validation script. What is the point in using a plugin that doesn't actually meet your needs? *sigh*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjc8611/5d3CT/3/ 
I removed all the events and the data, detached the element from its container, cleared the class from the container, emptied the container, and then readded the element. This seems like overkill to me, but I got my desired functionality. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the validation to a function that always returns true:

```
$("#element").valid8({
    jsFunctions: [{
        function: alwaysTrue, values: function() { return true; }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion; it doesn't seem to override what was previously set for the element. http://jsfiddle.net/sjc8611/5XrSZ/ Did I implement it incorrectly?